# Uploading Self Signed Cert Through MetaData SOAP

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, tooling-api, xml

I am trying to understand the right way to format a SOAP POST in order to upload a self-signed certificate into a scratch org.

Based on here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_certificate.htm

My goal is to do this through PowerShell. As such, I've looked through some posts:

https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/salesforce-com-accessing-using-web-services-and-scripting-part-1/
https://audministrator.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/salesforce-com-accessing-using-web-services-and-scripting-part-2/
https://www.powershellbros.com/send-soap-message-powershell/

For anyone familiar with Salesforce's SOAP structure - is that WSDL file only create-able if you create an application on your org?

Also, this is what I think I'd need to send as the envelope provided I had all the right parameters and values when I invoke my script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Certificate xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
        <caSigned>$true</caSigned>
        <encryptedWithPlatformEncryption>$true</encryptedWithPlatformEncryption>    
        <expirationDate>$ExpirationDate</expirationDate>
        <keySize>$KeySize</keySize>
        <masterLabel>$CertificateName</masterLabel>
        <privateKeyExportable>$false</privateKeyExportable>
</Certificate>
```

Am I missing anything with the XML? Anyone who's automated this (even partially), protips greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?